Unusual Memory Error when plotting line on secondary y axis using Pandas/Matplotlib
I'm getting the following memory error when adding a line to the secondary axis:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 48.2 GiB for an array with shape (1726364447,) and data type [('val', '<i8'), ('maj', '?'), ('min', '?'), ('fmt', 'S20')]

The error is generated when running the following in Jupyter notebook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

t = pd.Timestamp('2024-09-15 07:02:04')
times = []
for i in range(101):
    times.append(t)
    t = t + pd.Timedelta(f'{np.random.randint(7, 10)}s')

data1 = pd.Series(
    np.random.normal(size=101), 
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(times),
    name='Data 1'
)

data2 = pd.Series(
    [5.67, 5.85, 5.78], 
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-09-15 07:03:39", "2024-09-15 07:08:43", "2024-09-15 07:13:47"])
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 2.5))
data1.plot(ax=ax, style='.-')
data2.plot(ax=ax, style='.-', secondary_y=True)
ax.grid()
plt.show()

However, the error does not occur with just a minor change to the data.  For example if I change the time of the last point of the second data set from "2024-09-15 07:13:47" to "2024-09-15 07:12:47", the plot renders no problem:

Note that both datasets have an unevenly spaced datetime index.
Not sure if this is related to this error:

Memory error while plotting dataframe (matplotlib)

Can others reproduce this error?
Versions:

Python 3.10.12
pandas 2.1.2
matplotlib 3.8.2
numpy 1.26.1


Can reproduce. Seems to be related, the error on my end is in the same line mentioned here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8711#issuecomment-155924534

Thanks. That issue is closed since 2017.  Should I post a comment and ask them to relook at it with my example?

Known problem, issue can be found here: link
Can be fixed like this:
Firstly, data1.plot uses the pandas build in plotting function which integrates with matplotlib but introduces extra internal processing for ticks, labels and formatting (causing your memory error)
Change this (original):
data1.plot(ax=ax, style='.-')

To this:
Use matplotlib's plot method on ax directly.
ax.plot(data1.index, data1.values, '.-', label='Data 1')
ax.set_ylabel('Data 1')

Same for this line (original):
data2.plot(ax=ax, style='.-', secondary_y=True)

To this:
twinx() creates a secondary y-axis on the same plot without relying on pandas.
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data2.index, data2.values, '.-', color='orange', label='Data 2')
ax2.set_ylabel('Data 2')

optional: add tight_layout() as we added two y axis labels.

This should fix the issue, image above uses these data points:
data2 = pd.Series(
    [5.67, 5.85, 5.78], 
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-09-15 07:03:39", "2024-09-15 07:08:43", "2024-09-15 07:13:47"])
)

